# Generation of a nested list with different ranges

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Generation of a list of many lists each with different ranges

```
Isc_act = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
I_cel = []
a = []
for i in range(0,len(Isc_act)):
    a = np.arange(0, Isc_act[i], 0.1*Isc_act[i])
    I_cel[i].append(a)
print(I_cel)
```

Output is:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

My code is giving error. But, I want to get `I_cel = [[0,0.01,..,0.1],[0,0.02,0.04,...,0.2],[0, 0.03, 0.06,...,0.3]]`. Hence, the 'nested list' `I_cel` has three lists and each list has 10 values.

Comment: `I_cel` is empty.  There is no `I_cel[i]`.

Comment: There is another problem.. `[0,0.02,0.04,...,0.2]` should be 11 values, not 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest fix to your code, probably what you were intending to do:

```
Isc_act = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
I_cel = []
for i in range(0,len(Isc_act)):
    a = np.arange(0, Isc_act[i], 0.1*Isc_act[i])
    I_cel.append(a)
print(I_cel)
```

Note that the endpoint will be one step less than you wanted!  For example row zero, you have to pick two of the below:

- Steps of size 0.01
- Start point 0.0 and end point 0.1
- 10 elements total

You can not have all three.

More numpythonic approach:

```
>>> Isc_act = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
>>> (np.linspace(0, 1, 11).reshape(11,1) @ [Isc_act]).T
array([[0.  , 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1 ],
       [0.  , 0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.08, 0.1 , 0.12, 0.14, 0.16, 0.18, 0.2 ],
       [0.  , 0.03, 0.06, 0.09, 0.12, 0.15, 0.18, 0.21, 0.24, 0.27, 0.3 ]])
```

Comment: It just worked as I wanted. Excellent. If you don't mind, could you please explain what the `reshape(11,1)` does here? does it have to be same as last two elements in `np.linspace(0,1,11)`. I am beginner to python and I want to learn it.

Comment: Sure - the linspace returns a 1-d array of shape (11,), after the reshape it has a new dimension and is shape (11, 1).  Then it can be matrix multiplied by `Isc_act`, which is shape (1, 3), to produce an (11, 3).  Using .reshape(-1, 1) would also work the same (then the 11 is inferred from the input's shape).

Answer (score 1):

`linspace` gives better control of the end point when dealing with floats:

```
In [84]: [np.linspace(0,x,11) for x in [.1,.2,.3]]
Out[84]: 
[array([0.  , 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1 ]),
 array([0.  , 0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.08, 0.1 , 0.12, 0.14, 0.16, 0.18, 0.2 ]),
 array([0.  , 0.03, 0.06, 0.09, 0.12, 0.15, 0.18, 0.21, 0.24, 0.27, 0.3 ])]
```

Or we could scale just one array (`arange` with integers is predictable):

```
In [86]: np.array([.1,.2,.3])[:,None]*np.arange(0,11)
Out[86]: 
array([[0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1. ],
       [0. , 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1. , 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2. ],
       [0. , 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 1.5, 1.8, 2.1, 2.4, 2.7, 3. ]])
```

Comment: your solution is simple and too worked. Only problem is, appearance of `array` before each each list. How to eliminate that?

Comment: `np.linspace(0,x,11).tolist()` produces the list equivalent of an array.  Your attempt with `arange` also produces arrays, not lists.  `list(range(11))` is the Python list producer.