# Applying arange to an array

Tags: python, numpy

`np.arange` takes three arguments: start, stop, and step.

The step I want is -0.3048. I also have separate arrays for start and stop.

For start, I have a whole array of elements:

```
array([5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 4.377, 5.000,
       5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 3.462, 3.285,
       5.000, 5.000, 4.150, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 4.118, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 3.674, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000,
       5.000, 5.000, 4.655, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 4.573, 5.000, 5.000, 4.775, 4.909, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 3.874, 5.000, 5.000, 3.197, 5.000, 5.000,
       5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 4.829, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 4.372, 4.175, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000,
       5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 4.793, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 4.993, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000,
       5.000, 4.898, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 4.294, 5.000])
```

Here are the corresponding **stop** values:

```
array([1.927, -0.018, 0.214, 4.390, 0.162, 3.790, 4.891, -0.011, 4.623, 1.203, 4.270, 3.239, 4.569, 0.001, 3.942, 4.363, 3.135, 4.390, 3.176, 4.390,
       3.958, 3.992, 0.595, 4.458, 4.897, -0.009, -0.004, 0.004, 0.010, 4.987, 4.454, 3.167, 3.791, 4.213, 3.100, 4.312, 4.166, 3.942, 1.984, 2.077,
       4.810, 0.737, 0.490, 3.167, -0.010, 0.214, 4.313, 3.607, 2.509, 2.801, 3.034, 3.257, 0.013, 4.398, 0.013, 2.509, 4.157, 4.365, 4.902, 2.109,
       4.390, 3.176, 3.034, 4.096, 0.168, 3.205, 3.176, 1.927, 4.352, 2.509, 2.848, 4.749, 4.217, 3.017, 2.509, 4.204, 0.268, 1.662, 4.124, 0.136,
       2.509, 1.623, 4.791, 0.028, 2.969, 4.770, 4.799, 3.167, 2.970, 4.301, 0.883, 4.314, 0.182, -0.051, 2.493, 2.509, 4.131, 4.001, 4.952, 4.209,
       4.363, 4.632, 4.390, 3.172, 3.470, 0.174, 4.804, 2.247, 2.751, 4.352, 4.110, 2.969, 4.914, 2.142, 2.120, 4.936, 3.780, 3.942, 1.042, 4.229,
       2.267, 1.927, 1.213, 2.509, 4.464, 4.464, 0.595, 4.442, 2.751, 2.509, 3.339])
```

I need to apply arange to each element.

What is the fastest way to do this? I know I could use a for loop, but I'm hoping for a numpy-native solution (i.e. vectorized).

Thanks. Please let me know if anything is not clear.

Comment: If your `stop` is less than your `start`, `arange` gives you an empty array. Is that what you expect? Also, are you expecting an `arange` for each entry?

Comment: @C.Nivs The step is negative here

Comment: @MichaelButscher missed that, thanks

Comment: `arange` only works for one set of `start/step` values.  There isn't a version that works with multiple ones.  In some cases you can scale one range to get the rest.  But if the ranges differ in size, you have to generate each separately.

Comment: arange with floats is unpredictable when it comes to end point.

Comment: @hpaulj could you expand a bit more on that? Why is it unpredictable?

Comment: On the end point,  or something close to it, with `arange`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52470889/creating-a-sequence-of-regularly-spaced-numbers

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51413076/generation-of-a-nested-list-with-different-ranges

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create them on the fly, you could use a for loop:

```
starts = np.array([5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 4.377, 5.000,
   5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 3.462, 3.285,
   5.000, 5.000, 4.150, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 4.118, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 3.674, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000,
   5.000, 5.000, 4.655, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 4.573, 5.000, 5.000, 4.775, 4.909, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 3.874, 5.000, 5.000, 3.197, 5.000, 5.000,
   5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 4.829, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 4.372, 4.175, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000,
   5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 4.793, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 4.993, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000,
   5.000, 4.898, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 4.294, 5.000])

stops = np.array([1.927, -0.018, 0.214, 4.390, 0.162, 3.790, 4.891, -0.011, 4.623, 1.203, 4.270, 3.239, 4.569, 0.001, 3.942, 4.363, 3.135, 4.390, 3.176, 4.390,
   3.958, 3.992, 0.595, 4.458, 4.897, -0.009, -0.004, 0.004, 0.010, 4.987, 4.454, 3.167, 3.791, 4.213, 3.100, 4.312, 4.166, 3.942, 1.984, 2.077,
   4.810, 0.737, 0.490, 3.167, -0.010, 0.214, 4.313, 3.607, 2.509, 2.801, 3.034, 3.257, 0.013, 4.398, 0.013, 2.509, 4.157, 4.365, 4.902, 2.109,
   4.390, 3.176, 3.034, 4.096, 0.168, 3.205, 3.176, 1.927, 4.352, 2.509, 2.848, 4.749, 4.217, 3.017, 2.509, 4.204, 0.268, 1.662, 4.124, 0.136,
   2.509, 1.623, 4.791, 0.028, 2.969, 4.770, 4.799, 3.167, 2.970, 4.301, 0.883, 4.314, 0.182, -0.051, 2.493, 2.509, 4.131, 4.001, 4.952, 4.209,
   4.363, 4.632, 4.390, 3.172, 3.470, 0.174, 4.804, 2.247, 2.751, 4.352, 4.110, 2.969, 4.914, 2.142, 2.120, 4.936, 3.780, 3.942, 1.042, 4.229,
   2.267, 1.927, 1.213, 2.509, 4.464, 4.464, 0.595, 4.442, 2.751, 2.509, 3.339])

step = -0.3048
if len(starts)!=len(stops):
    raise IndexError("Shape of starts does not match shape of stops")

for i in range(len(starts)):
    myrange = np.arange(starts[i], stops[i], step)
    # do things
```

Getting a little fancier:

```
pairs = list(zip(starts, stops))

for start, stop in pairs:
    myrange = np.arange(start, stop, step)
```

I'm sure there's a nicer `numpy`-native implementation, but this can get you off the ground

Comment: I am hoping for a numpy-native implementation, but failing that I will use something like you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: If the resulting arrays differ in length, there isn't nice numpy-native approach.  Ragged arrays are not native.

Comment: Quick note, if your arrays are sufficiently large, it is better design to keep the `zip`  call in the declaration of the `for` loop: `for start, stop in zip(starts, stops)`. This will keep `zip` as a generator and keep it from eating up memory in the cache by duplicating lists